# Recover Extended Partition

Tags: truecrypt, mbr

I have a serious problem. I lost my MBR. But that is first of the problems.

My disk layout was something like this (more less);
sda1 truecrypt-os 80GB
sda2 ext4 8GB
sda3 swap 4GB
(sda4) extended
(sda5) truecrypt 1,8TB
(sda6) ext4 24GB

Windows decided to crash and wipe MBR and few of the first sectors.

Is there any way to find and "plant" sda4 to MBR? I don't care much about primary partitions. All my sensitive data are on extended partitions.

My disk is currently being scanned by gpart and testdisk, but I feel that this will have bad results.

Do you know any tool that I can command to search and recover extended partition entry? It would be cool if I can specify to search from x to y, this would save a lot of time.

Please help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ahh, no problem, you do have a backup of your precious data ... right?

Comment: This question is off-topic for StackOverflow, as it's not programming or programmer tool related. The [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) is very clear about the types of questions that are proper to ask here. General computer and operating system questions are not among them. (Unrelated, but you might also want to take a few minutes to read this [How does accepting an answer work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). It's nice if you actually participate here rather than just asking for help and showing no appreciation when you get it.)

Comment: Sorry, I was in a bit of hurry, thanks for moving this question here.

Comment: @aefxx: I have backup f most my data (source codes and such), but not all, for example pictures we have on that disk uses 1.3TB, about 500GB are on DVD's.. I have only one 2TB disk :( Such a disk is quite expensive for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are indeed tools that can sniff for an extended partition - gpart is a good starting point as you've found. Have a read of http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/linux/docs/howto/other-formats/html_single/Partition-Rescue.html and try googling "rescue extended partition." If you have another disk, I would firstly make a byte-by-byte copy of the entire disk in case you break anything...

Comment: gpart actually failed due to read error, I left my PC running with testdisk. When I was leaving results were promising. As for breaking things... MBR is already broken :P

Answer (score 0):

If any one has a problem like me:

[TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) has managed to restore some of my partitions including large truecrypt encrypted NTFS one. Unfortunately damaged severely partition table.

I asked another question in topic of restoring partition table to it's former glory. ( [Fixing damaged partition table](https://superuser.com/questions/503601/fixing-damaged-partition-table) )